# How do I make a UIRefreshControl reappear after hiding it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableViewController and UIRefreshControl set up. The refreshControl works and reloads the tableView. The issue is that I have a UISegmentedControl above my tableView which reloads the tableView with different data, depending on which segment you clicked on. Now I only want the refreshControl to be able to work on the first segment (which is also the default) and I want to disable it for the other two UISegmentedControl elements. Here's a screenshot of the tableView:
 [image: UITableView with attached UISegmentedControl]

Now, I hide it simply by setting `self.refreshControl = nil` and this works fine. The problem is that once I've done that (by clicking on one of the other UISC elements), I can't get it back to work in the default table. I've tried simply resetting `self.refreshControl = savedRefreshControl` after the @"Aktuelle Rezepte" element is selected, but this doesn't work. I further tried simply disabling and hiding it using

```
[self.refreshControl setEnabled:NO];
[self.refreshControl setHidden:YES];
```

and then resetting both of these when needed, but this does not work as well. What are your thoughts? Am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - it was a stupid mistake. I declared `savedRefreshControl` at the top of my UITableViewController but set its property to `(weak, nonatomic)` instead of `(strong, nonatomic)`, that's why resetting `self.refreshControl` didn't work. 
As has been mentioned in other posts, make sure that you don't do `self.refreshControl = nil` while it's still refreshing, as it screws up the app and refreshing logic.